# STL container(vector)

Tags: c++, vector, stl, return

my question is what good does the following code do , I have used it with a class to store
objects...

```
product& productDB:: Push_in(std::string a_name,std::string a_brand,std::string a_supply,float x, float y)
{
  product temp;
 temp.mf_setProductName(a_name);
 temp.mf_setBrandName(a_brand);
 temp.mf_setSupplier(a_supply);
 temp.mf_setReceivingPrice( x);
 temp.mf_setRrp(y);
 Goods.push_back(temp);
return Goods[Goods.size()-1];
}
```

why can't i just return  Goods
thanks in advance

Comment: It's impossible to even guess based only on the code you've posted.

Comment: Your code. You tell us.

Answer (score 0):

what it does:
it 'push(es)_in' a product into your `Goods` collection.

why cant you return `Goods`? 
because `push_in`'s signature says it returns a `product` reference